# Reading the content of a JS file using JS

Tags: javascript, dom, cors, fetch

I am trying to read the content inside a javascript file that is included inside the script tag.

```js
const script = document.querySelector("script");

fetch(script.getAttribute('src'))
.then((res) =>
    res.text().then((txt) => {
                 console.log(txt);
                 //this will have the content of the file
                })
  ).catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <script src="reader.js"></script>
    <!--reader.js will read the content of index.js file-->
  </body>
</html>
```

I am getting the following error

```
Fetch API cannot load file:///C:/Users/intel/OneDrive/Desktop/devl/index.js. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.
```

I know that if I use live server it will work, however, I wanted to know how to make this work if I am not using live server.

Answer (score -2):

Fetch api only works in a live server, it is normal.